# Angular 2 events fires twice

Tags: angular, ionic2

I built my app with angular 2 and ionic. My app contains around 15 different components that is lazy loaded, when opened I send some data to the component.

Every component uses an extend class with no component bound to it (just an ordinary class).

If I load one of these components, the constructor and lifecycle events fires twice, which results in the data being empty the second time. However if I do load the SAME component again, it does not fire twice. If i load another component it fires twice, if I go back to the first component that already loaded once the events fires twice.

Anyone has a clue what I am doing wrong here?

Edit: All "start"-lifecycle events fires twice, even the constructor of the class. I logged all events, ngOnInit, ngAfterContentInit, and Ionics events as ionViewDidLoad, ionViewWillEnter.

I did an very very UGLY fix now and hope I can solve this better, on the first load I set the data to an global variable and on the second load I get that variable instead of params.

Comment: Could you be more specific and say which life-cycle events fire, or show some example code?

Comment: ll "start"-lifecycle events fires twice, even the constructor of the class. I logged all events, ngOnInit, ngAfterContentInit, and Ionics events as ionViewDidLoad, ionViewWillEnter.

Comment: If the constructor runs twice, so there are probably 2 instances of this component.

Comment: Well I have 15 components that is extended with this class because they have very much in common.  Is that the problem? Is there a way to solve this?